How to trigger Windows 11 update at the startup?
I am currently using Windows 10 Pro as my operating system. Recently, Microsoft
announced on April 27, 2023, that support for Windows 10 will end on October 14, 2025.
It's not hard to find a link to install Windows 11 but I want to trigger the update at startup
Additionally, I noticed a prompt for a Windows 11 update during startup at random:

How to trigger Windows 11 update at the startup?

You can’t manually. You can install Windows 11 through Windows Update. That’s all that “Get it” will actually do, that’s actually a lie, as the update is already been prepared and stagged.

April 27, 2023 is not recently


April 27, 2023 is not recently

My bad.

As for triggering at startup, that may be some random flag somewhere...  If you want to install Windows 11, here is a link from Microsoft for the different methods:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ways-to-install-windows-11-e0edbbfb-cfc5-4011-868b-2ce77ac7c70e

It's not hard to find a link to install Windows 11 but I want to trigger the update at startup. Can you edit your answer? Is it possible by tweaking regedit ?

@JulianJackson - It’s not possible to manually trigger, however, it should happen more than once. There a reason you are not just going into Windows Update and hitting a button?
